# Primefaces p:calendar component is not working for Saturday and Sunday

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

My sql code is

```
SELECT d FROM deneme d WHERE d.createdDate between :startDate AND :stopDate ORDER BY d.createdDate ASC
```

My primefaces codes are

```
<p:calendar id="basla" value="#{denemeBean.startDate}" pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy"/>  
<p:calendar id="bit"   value="#{denemeBean.stopDate}"  pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
```

When I choose dates between starDate = 20-04-2014 Sunday and stopDate = 22-04-2014 Tuesday,
I see data's date start with 19-04-2014 Saturday and stop with 21-04-2014 Monday

And also startDate = 19-04-2014 Saturday and stopDate = 22-04-2014 Tuesday, the data's date start with 18-04-2014 Saturday and stop with 21-04-2014 Monday

DenemeBean

`public class DenemeBean implements Serializable {

```
private Date startDate = new Date();
private Date stopDate = new Date();


public DenemeBean () {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    startDate = DateUtils.addDays(startDate, -1);


}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getStopDate() {
    return stopDate;
}

public void setStopDate(Date stopDate) {
    this.stopDate = stopDate;
}
```

}
`

Comment: That's weird. Where's your backing bean code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :) with timeZone component

```
<p:calendar id="basla" value="#{denemeBean.startDate}" pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy" timeZone="GMT+3" />
```